# C++ templates error: instantiated from 'void TestClass::testMethod(T, std::map) [with T = SomeClass]

Tags: c++, templates

I've some problem in my code I cannot deal with:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H_
#define TESTCLASS_H_

#include <map>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass(){};
  virtual ~TestClass(){};
  void testMethod(T b,std::map<T,int> m);
};

template <typename T>
void TestClass<T>::testMethod(T b,std::map<T,int> m){
  m[b]=0;
}
#endif /*TESTCLASS_H_*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  SomeClass s;
  TestClass<SomeClass> t;
  map<SomeClass,int> m;
  t.testMethod(s,m);
}
```

Compiler gives me following error in line m[b]=0; :

instantiated from 'void TestClass::testMethod(T, std::map) [with T = SomeClass]

Could you help find the problem??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format code using the `101010` button on the edit page.

Comment: Please paste in the full error message. What you have pasted is just the top of the template instantiation traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Not even seeing the error, I can tell you one thing that you probably are doing wrong. Here:

```
void TestClass<T>::testMethod(T b,std::map<T,int> m){
```

You are aware, that you're taking a whole map **by value**?

That however, is not the source of the error. Map is a sorted associative container, and expects keys that can be sorted. Built in types have their sorting via the `<` operator. For your own class, you need to either provide an operator, or initialize the map with a custom sorting functor.

Hence either an operator:

```
bool operator<(const SomeClass&,const SomeClass&)
{ 
     return ...;
}
```

...or a functor:

```
struct CompareSomeClass {
  bool operator()(const SomeClass&,const SomeClass&) 
  {
      return ...;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
#include <map>

class SomeClass {};

bool operator<(const SomeClass&,const SomeClass&);

class in {};

template <typename T>
class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass(){};
  virtual ~TestClass(){};
  void testMethod(T b,std::map<T,int> m);
};

template <typename T>
void TestClass<T>::testMethod(T b,std::map<T,int> m){
  m[b]=0;
}

int main() {
  SomeClass s;
  TestClass<SomeClass> t;
  std::map<SomeClass,int> m;
  t.testMethod(s,m);
}
```

compiles just fine for me using VC10 and Comeau.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `SomeClass` does not have `operator<` defined for it.  Define that and you should be good to go:

```
bool operator<(const SomeClass &sc1, const SomeClass sc2)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Overloading operator < in SomeClass solved problem:

```
bool operator<(const SomeClass &s1) const{
    ....
 }
```

Thanks a lot!